# Weird behavior when trying to compare field to 0 in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say i have 2 records in my db:

```
--  Name  -- approved -- resolved
-- Record1 --    1     --    0
-- Record2 --    1     --    1
```

I'm fetching the records with Where clause

```
$results = DB::table('mytable')->where('mytable.approved','=',1)->where('mytable.resolved','=',0);
```

The weird behavior is that it's refusing to fetch `Record1` row if `resolved=0` ,

if i change the query to

```
$results = DB::table('mytable')->where('mytable.approved','=',1)->where('mytable.resolved','>',0);
```

It does fetch `Record2` .

Anyone has an idea what's wrong?

I tried playing with the field type and make it boolean and null , didn't help.

Comment: tried a >= instead ? i never used laravel but maybe it can work o.o

Comment: What type is your "resolved" field? (And bear in mind that numeric types don't need the quotes around the values...)

Comment: Shouldn't it be ==? I just happened to click this question and honestly have no idea though.

Comment: I just accidentally added the quotes on the numbers when i wrote the question (fixed), the actual code doesn't have them.

Comment: if your field type is bool try true/false rather than 1/0 or try the field type as a tinyint and use 1/0

Comment: This might be a long shot, but has the record been soft deleted?

Comment: @G_V Databases generally use `=` as the comparison operator. Laravel's query builder is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Use whereRaw  may be the below code work for you

$results = DB::table('mytable')->whereRaw("mytable.approved = 1 AND mytable.resolved = 0");

try this

it solved your problem.